# WCF Service Call Failing...What's Wrong With My Config Files?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, web-services

I've got a C# WCF service that passes a collection of instantiated .Net objects to the caller.  Works fine, however if I try to pass too many objects in the collection it fails with the following exception:

```
{"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://myserver/MyAppService/MyAppService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details."}
{"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."}
{"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}
{"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"}
```

It's fully reproduceable and is definitely related to the number objects in the collection and not the contents of the object.

Based on another post I made about it, I tried making changes to both my client side app.config file and the service server side web.config file.  However the changes did not fix the problem, which makes me think it's possible I did not set up my config files correctly.

Below is my client-side app.config file (non-related stuff removed):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_iMyAppService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <client>      
    <endpoint address="http://myserver/MyAppService/MyAppService.svc"
    behaviorConfiguration="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_iMyAppService"
    contract="MyAppService.iMyAppService" name="BasicHttpBinding_iMyAppService" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And here is my server-side web.config file (non-related stuff removed):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_iMyAppService"
             closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  <services>
    <service name="MyApp_WCFService.MyAppService">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost/MyAppService/"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyApp_WCFService.iMyAppService" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_iMyAppService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Do these look correct?  If so, is there anything I'm missing in either one that would make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the WCF Service Configuration Editor, or are you manually modifying these files?

Comment: I manually modified the files after they were auto created.  The configuration editor gives errors on simple .config files without any modification.

Comment: Anyone else see anything that could be wrong?

Comment: I suggest using the Configuration Editor to get the configuration to not have errors.  I've not experienced the issue with basic config files having errors as you say.  I'd also check the Event Log on the  server for the error to get more context. Finally, try setting up a WSHttpBinding on the client and server and use that instead of Basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it...Finally.  The problem was that on the server-side web.config, the behavior maxItemsInObjectGraph had to be a servicebehavior, not an endpoint behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the service logging available, it makes finding the actual problem much easier

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx

To start, Add this to your web.config and then find the file using the viewer (SvcTraceViewer.exe)

Which for me is located here (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin)

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing" >
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
        <add initializeData="App_tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp"/>
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: I did.  I see the exception in there, but i don't see any additional information other than what I already had, unfortunately.  Anything in particular I should look for?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the mex endpoint?